# What algorithm is the code as follow?(it seems to be base64, but some different)

Tags: javascript, encryption, base64

I have a code snippet as follow:

```
function budget(e, t) {
  return e === 64 ? 64 : e === 63 ? t : e >= t ? e + 1 : e;
}


function myencode(bin, budget) {
  var b64ch = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
  var b64chs = Array.prototype.slice.call(b64ch);
  var b = typeof budget !== "undefined" ? Math.floor(Math.random() *64) : -1;

  var u32, c0, c1, c2, asc = '';
  var pad = bin.length % 3;

  for (var i = 0; i < bin.length;) {
    if ((c0 = bin.charCodeAt(i++)) > 255 ||
        (c1 = bin.charCodeAt(i++)) > 255 ||
        (c2 = bin.charCodeAt(i++)) > 255)
        throw new TypeError('invalid character found');
    u32 = (c0 << 16) | (c1 << 8) | c2;
    if (typeof budget === "undefined") {
      asc += b64chs[u32 >> 18 & 63]
          + b64chs[u32 >> 12 & 63]
          + b64chs[u32 >> 6 & 63]
          + b64chs[u32 & 63];
    } else {
      asc += b64chs[budget(u32 >> 18 & 63, b)]
          + b64chs[budget(u32 >> 12 & 63, b)]
          + b64chs[budget(u32 >> 6 & 63, b)]
          + b64chs[budget(u32 & 63, b)];
    }
  }

  return (pad ? asc.slice(0, pad - 3) + "===".substring(pad) : asc) + (b64chs[b] || "")
}

console.log(myencode("test-string", budget))
```

According to [js-base64](https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64/blob/main/base64.js#L71) I know this code is 99% `base64` algorithm, but it has a `budget` function, what does this used for? And I also want to know how can I decode?

Answer (score 0):

The additional code looks like a kind of cipher that includes its key at the end of the output, enciphering input bytes above a random threshold by incrementing them. It looks like a cheap way to pass a low stakes secret in the open.

How to decode?

Idea 0: don't use this. js-base64 works fine in both directions.

Idea 1: find the `mydecode` function wherever the encoder was found.

Idea 2: It looks like one can decipher by grabbing the value of `b` from the end of the encoded string and decrementing input bytes that exceed `b` (special cases for the values `b` itself and 64). If this fails, see Ideas 0 and 1.

Demo of successful decode when `budget` is null.

```js
function budget(e, t) {
  return e === 64 ? 64 : e === 63 ? t : e >= t ? e + 1 : e;
}


function myencode(bin, budget) {
  var b64ch = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
  var b64chs = Array.prototype.slice.call(b64ch);
  var b = typeof budget !== "undefined" ? Math.floor(Math.random() *64) : -1;

  var u32, c0, c1, c2, asc = '';
  var pad = bin.length % 3;

  for (var i = 0; i < bin.length;) {
    if ((c0 = bin.charCodeAt(i++)) > 255 ||
        (c1 = bin.charCodeAt(i++)) > 255 ||
        (c2 = bin.charCodeAt(i++)) > 255)
        throw new TypeError('invalid character found');
    u32 = (c0 << 16) | (c1 << 8) | c2;
    if (typeof budget === "undefined") {
      asc += b64chs[u32 >> 18 & 63]
          + b64chs[u32 >> 12 & 63]
          + b64chs[u32 >> 6 & 63]
          + b64chs[u32 & 63];
    } else {
      asc += b64chs[budget(u32 >> 18 & 63, b)]
          + b64chs[budget(u32 >> 12 & 63, b)]
          + b64chs[budget(u32 >> 6 & 63, b)]
          + b64chs[budget(u32 & 63, b)];
    }
  }

  return (pad ? asc.slice(0, pad - 3) + "===".substring(pad) : asc) + (b64chs[b] || "")
}

let message = "test-string";
console.log('message', message)
let enc = myencode(message);
console.log('encoded', enc)
let dec = Base64.decode(enc)
console.log('decoded', dec)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-base64@3.7.3/base64.min.js"></script>
```